# Mac OS X Embedded Helper App Bundle Code Signing

Tags: xcode, macos, sandbox, code-signing, appstore-sandbox

I'm at the beta testing phase with my new app, but I've run into a problem that I've spent two days researching and experimenting with.

The app is for the Mac App Store. I'm letting Xcode 5 automatically handle the code signing and provisioning, so in Build Settings the Code Signing Identity is just set to "`Mac Developer`". I'm also using the `--deep` option (I know it's not recommended) to sign all of the embedded frameworks that the app contains.  The main app also contains an embedded helper app (an actual *.app* bundle, which might be the problem).

- The app compiles without issue.
- It passes an App Store verification just fine.
- I can run the app from within Xcode and the main app can launch the helper help.
- I can also run the app from the build location in the Finder, and can still launch the helper app.

The problem comes when I move the app outside the build folder, or put it on another computer to test. The main app runs just fine (and all Apple services, like MapKit, function OK) but the main app cannot launch the helper app, the Console logs say:

```
lsboxd[344]: Not allowing process 18553 to launch "/Users/Brian/Desktop/MainApp.app/Contents/MacOS/HelperApp.app" because the security assessment verdict was denied.

lsboxd[344]: Not allowing process 18553 to register app "/Users/Brian/Desktop/MainApp.app/Contents/MacOS/HelperApp.app" for launch.
```

Clearly there's some code signing/sandbox issue going on. It's possible that everything *might* work after it's submitted to Apple and a user downloads it through the App Store, but I'd rather be able to test it *before* it gets that far.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you think it's a code signing problem, this is a great guide: http://furbo.org/2013/10/17/code-signing-and-mavericks/

Comment: What do you get if you run the command `spctl -a -v path/to/MainApp.app`?

Comment: Running `spctl -a -v path/to/MainApp.app` returns "rejected". Which is not encouraging. I ran it on my Debug build as well as an Archived Application signed with my Mac Developer cert for that app. Though changing user/group and then running the app from Applications as suggested by Lionel_A does allow the helper app to run.

Comment: I ran both builds of my app through RB App Checker Lite which pointed out a problem:  `Gatekeeper assessment: FAIL (missing/invalid authority).`  raw assessment: {
    "assessment:authority" =     {
    };
    "assessment:originator" = "Mac Developer: Brian Toth (########)";
    "assessment:remote" = 1;
    "assessment:verdict" = 0;
}

Answer (score 1):

You should give the right permissions to the main app and to the helper before you launch the app outside of the build location.

system   : read and write

wheel    : read only

everyone : read only

In my app, I've set the Code Signing Identity to Mac App Store. It seems that the app must also reside into the /Application folder.

Comment: That does allow the helper app to run, so it'll do for testing right now. Though running `spctl -a -v path/to/MainApp.app` as suggested above resulted in a "rejected" result.

Comment: I'm developing an app with a helper. When I run spctl -a -v, I also get a rejected status. I will investigate. But your app passes the App Store verification.